# how to echo the value of foreach loop in php

Tags: php

I have written a foreach loop for displaying the minimum and maximum interest rate but i am not getting how to echo the value of it. Here i have only used interest rate min. But i want to echo 
only **minimum rate of interest** when the minimum and maximum value are same and **both values** to be display when minimum and maximum rate of interest not matching.

```
                  <?php if(count($json['resultList']) > 0): ?>
      <?php 
        foreach ($json['resultList'] as $key=>$value) {
            if($json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"] == $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"]){
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"];
            }
            else{
                $interest = $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"].' - '.$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMax"];
}
                echo '
  <div class="cr-content">                
                <div class="bank-rates">
      <ul>
   <li><div class="innr-spl" style="padding: 5px 0;"><span style="display:block;"><img src="'.$json["resultList"][$key]["imageUrl"].'"></span>
   <span class="hide">Muthoot Finance</span>      
   </div></li>


   <li><div class="innr-spl2">'.$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"].'%'.'</div></li>
   <li><div class="innr-spl2">60</div> </li>
   <li class="hide"><div class="innr-spl3 view-detail1" id="'.$key.'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>View Datails</div> </li>
      </ul>
      <div style="clear:both"></div>
                            <div class="bannerin" id="ban_'.$key.'"> 
      <ul class="details" id="details1">
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Maximum Loan Amount : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["loanEligibility"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Max Tenure (In Years) : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["tenure"].'</li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> Interest Rate Type : '.$json["resultList"][$key]["rateType"].'</li>

      </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

                ';
                $i++;
        }

    ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: That's not even valid PHP. Can you fix it then give us the actual code.

Comment: @JonStirling Thats valid PHP?

Comment: @Xatenev Um.. What?

Comment: With the update, that's better.

Comment: this is my actual code.

Comment: `<li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"] . '%' . '</div></li>` =>    `<li><div class="innr-spl2">' . $interest . '%' . '</div></li>` probably? If I see it correctly your doing the needed `if()` on top of the page already. Just use the value now :)

Comment: please mention where to display it. or you just want to echo it

Comment: Use your `$interest` variable instead of the `$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"]` in your `div` with %

Comment: I want to display. i am able to echo it. here i want to display

Comment: <li><div class="innr-spl2">'.$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"].'%'.'</div></li>

Comment: I tried using $interest variable but it failed to load the data

Comment: can you tell me exact way to call $interest ?

Comment: @user3548039 Just copy the snippet from my comment above...

Comment: do you want to display inside foreach as a div

Comment: @Xatenev Thanks it worked

Comment: Change `$json["resultList"][$key]["interestRateMin"]` to `$value['intersertRateMin']` (same for max rate) and check the value of `$interest` after the if-section

Comment: your code is spaghetti you should try and learn how to separate code logic  from everything including html and then render a nice html with data from php.